# Change the name of added worksheet

Tags: vbscript

```
objWriteWorkbook.sheets.add ,objWriteWorkbook.sheets(objWriteWorkbook.sheets.count)
Set NewWorksheetObject = objWriteWorkbook.Worksheets(num)
objWriteWorkbook.Sheets(num).Name = sheetName
```

I wanted to change the name of added worksheet.
Adding of sheet and object creation for that sheet is working fine but when I try to change the name of the sheet I am getting an error **"Unknown runtime error"**

Can any one help how can change the name of added sheet.

Answer (score 4):

Assign the new sheet to a variable when you add it:

```
Set ws = wb.Sheets.Add(, wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
ws.Name = sheetName
```

Answer (score 1):

```
set xlo=CreateObject("excel.application")
set wbo=xlo.workbooks.open("C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\Temp.xlsx")
Set ws = wbo.Sheets.Add(, wbo.Sheets("sheet1"))
ws.Name = "Priyesh"


wbo.save
wbo.close
xlo.quit
set wbo=nothing 
set xlo=Nothing
```